# modify android.server.BluetoothService.java to update cached service_channel_no of paired device to open multiple connections to it(on mul. channels)

Tags: android, browser, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am stuck at a place where my Android Phone(Samsung Galaxy) has to open 2(or more) connections to my PC(server) which is a paired device. For this purpose, I start SDP server on PC with UUID : 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB and channel 2, after the first connection I unregister the SDP service on the PC and register it again on channel 3(and same UUID) and expect my android phone to 'connect' to it for establishing the second bluetooth connection. The second one fails.

The problem as I have figured out is that because of the pairing, the channel num and UUID of the device for the 'BluetoothSocket.connect' are serviced from cache and are not being updated, so my SDP change in channel num on the server side is not visible here as it still tries to connect to channel 2(old one).

A workaround of this problem(found after a lot of frustrating attempts) might be to change the android.server.BluetoothService.java file, by introducing 
updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(addr) before returning in the getRemoteServiceChannel() and fetchRemoteUuids() so as to update the channel number at each func call.

The above solution may well be wrong, please pardon me for that. If it is correct please suggest any further changes and how to make this change permanent in eclipse, or in other case(wrong solution), the right way of doing this.

Note: I have android 2.3.5 and the requests from the device are actually from the browser that I forward to the PC. I want them on separate channels.

thanks.