# modify android sdk and reflect changes in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

In relation to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218252/modify-android-server-bluetoothservice-java-to-update-cached-service-channel-no), I have to modify the android SDK - specifically the file: /home/me/android-sdk-linux/sources/android-16/android/server/BluetoothService.java. I am using eclipse, how should I reload the sdk after the changes.

The SDK Manager shows a non-editable directory path, and reinstallation of the packages starts downloads from the web. How can I reflect my own local changes.

I am just a beginner, ignore any naivety in question.

Thanks

Comment: You need to compile it again. There are some tutorials for that, a simple search should give you a head start...