# In Android's bluetooth, does BluetoothSocket.connect invoke SDP to get fresh channel

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, sdp

As a continuation to the question's title, I obtain the BluetoothSocket by selecting a *BluetoothDevice* device from my paired devices and doing:

```
bSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
bSocket.connect();
```

My question is this: suppose at the time of pairing the channel for communication over the UUID was recorded as channel-2, but at the time of connect the other device has switched its listener to channel 3 and is advertising service on channel-3 for the same myUUID.

When I do a *connect*, will it be trying to connect to channel-2(in cache, refer to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218252/modify-android-server-bluetoothservice-java-to-update-cached-service-channel-no)) or will it(.connect command) do a fresh SDP to get the current channel i.e 3 and try to connect to channel 3 (and myUUID).

Is it possible to see which channel was tried by *connect* command.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is some hidden(obscured) functionality on Android for Bluetooth which may help.
It is called IBluetooth.
**[Here](http://snipplr.com/view/49526/get-ibluetooth-instance/)** is a description of how to use it.

Once you get it running, try the *getRemoteServiceChannel* function and the *onRfcommChannelFound* callback - it will get the correct channeld and respectively show what channel was found for your UUID.

Normally, with your error, I would expect you get the channel 2 on first connect, and then get nothing. This means Android was lazy and did not do another SDP browse.

How to get them to connect properly? Maybe if you are in luck, after channel 2 connect, calling these hidden functions will refresh its SDP database?!
Another way is to unbond them and rebond them programatically - I suspect that will make it do another SDP browse...

Don't forget to vote up if useful

Comment: @curiosbill you can post more questions along the way. Happy to help